# How do you extract values from a comma separated list of values when some are null?

Tags: java, string

A web service I'm using returns a comma separated list of values:

```
a,b,,d,,f,,h,,j,,l,,,
```

How I you extract these into their respective container variables when some of them are empty?

```
String a = ...;
String b = ...;
String c = ...;
String d = ...;
String e = ...;
String f = ...;
String g = ...;
String h = ...;
String i = ...;
String j = ...;
String k = ...;
String l = ...;
```

Comment: The point most seem to be missing is that Mocktagish wants to preserve the missing values, not necessarily assign them to  variables named a, b, c, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] result = "a,b,,d,,f,,h,,j,,l,,,".split(",");
```

Then you can allocate your a, b, c, etc. to elements of `result`

```
String a = result[0];
...
```

Comment: Ummm ... `String.split(...)` returns a `String[]`

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] arr = yourString.split(",", -1);
String a = arr[0];
String b = arr[1];
...etc...
```

Empty strings will be returned as `""`, including the ones at the end. So `"a,b,,".split(",", -1)` will result in the following array: `{ "a", "b", "", "" }`

If, on the other hand, you are not interested in the trailing strings if they are empty, do:

```
String[] arr = yourString.split(",");
```

This way, the trailing empty strings (if there are any) will be removed. `"a,b,,".split(",")` will therefore result in `{ "a", "b" }`

Comment: How do you subtract 1 from a string?

Comment: You're missing a comma in the argument list to split().

Comment: You're definitely right. Too many commas there, missed the ona needed. :-) Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using an array instead of the individual variables, `a,b,...`.  Then you could simply use `split` as others have suggested and be done with it:

```
String full_line = // get the full line from your web service.
String[] abc_etc = full_line.split(",");
// abc_etc now contains all fields, in order.  
// Do note that empty fields are stored as "", not null.
```

If you *really* need to store them in individual variables, you'll need to do it one at a time:

```
String full_line = // get the full line from your web service.
String[] fields = full_line.split(",");
String a = fields[0];
String b = fields[1];
String c = fields[2];
...
```

If you want `null` instead of `""`, add a check:

```
String a = fields[0].equals("")? null : fields[0];
```